# PERMISSIONS READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Needed for RNFetchBlob >CacheDir

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rn-fetch-blob

“I am using React Native CLI and have RNFetchBlob.fs in my project. I use the CacheDir folder to save and access recorded audio files. My question is, do I need to add the permissions READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in my AndroidManifest.xml file? I am using cache memory (app-specific storage), not shareable storage. I plan to upload my app to Google Play and want to ensure that I don’t face any rejections related to these runtime permissions. Moreover, if I place any permission in my manifest and I am not using that permission in my app, could this cause any issue?”

```
  
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

"I am trying to make an audio player app(recording audio in cacheDir). My concern is whether I need to add these permissions to the AndroidManifest.xml file or not:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Or will this permission work perfectly?

````
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```"

``` buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        kotlinVersion = '1.6.10'
````

Comment: hi take a look at the official documentation,  after the API 33 you can use this: 

Note: Starting in API level 33, this permission has no effect. If your app accesses other apps' media files, request one or more of these permissions instead: READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, READ_MEDIA_VIDEO, READ_MEDIA_AUDIO. Learn more about the storage permissions that are associated with media files.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: “I think I missed that part of the documentation. Thanks for the help, it was very useful.

Comment: Hi Muhammand Asif, if this solved your problem, please mark the comment as the solution. Thanks